# System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, ria

I am getting the following error in WCF+Silverlight+RIA Service application. It's happening only on production DB.

I copied the production DB to my development machine, I am getting that error when I point the web.config to my production DB from development environment. If I point to test DB then everything works fine.

So I thought that some mismatch problem in DB so I tried to compare test and production DB and all the DB structures are same.

This error occurs only on one function/query 'GetEventViewAll', all other operations are working on that DB. So I thought that the function 'GetEventViewAll' returns more rows, so I deleted all rows on that table, but still getting that error.

This error happens only on production DB, not production environment. I am using same machine, same code, same VS2010. I am just making changes only on web.config to point other DB(production) then getting error.

Could anyone please tell me what I missed or what needs to be done?

the error from output window of VS2010 is: 
`` {System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetEventViewAll'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}
    [System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException]: {System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetEventViewAll'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    InnerException: {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}
    Message: "Load operation failed for query 'GetEventViewAll'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
    StackTrace: null ``

Comment: check if you got access to the prod DB server

Comment: @K.B I did backup the prod DB and restored in my development PC. When I connect that restored DB(prod DB) I am getting that error only on a particular function, other operations are working fine.

Comment: have u maded any changes to the DB schema

Comment: @K.B yes, I made some changes and I did the same in prod DB also. I used dbdiff tool to compare the DB both structures are same.

Comment: @K.B thanks KB, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved by adding Query-HasSideEffects attribute to the function.

```
[Query(HasSideEffects = true)]    //<--- this line solved the problem
public IQueryable<EventView> GetEventView(List<string> siteName)
{
 .....
}
```

I passed a list to that function. That list is filled from a table. Test DB has less values, production DB has more values, the list count was more in production db. So I got the following error

```
The Maximum URI length of 2083 was exceeded
```

so I put Query attribute to that function to resolve!

Comment: (In Silverlight)if add Attributes [Query(HasSideEffects = true)]. Query load occurs fail when add .Where() or .OrderBy(). Have you solve that?
Example: _domainServiceAtClient.Load(query.Where(p=>p.ID = _id)).

Comment: Update: Error occurs when deploy web.